# Hierarchical GTAGS TAG file

Tags: emacs, gnu-global

One liner: I am looking for a "Hierarchical" Tags file setup whereas if `global` cannot find the `TAGSDB` in the `GTAGSDBPATH` directory then it climbs up the dir chain till it finds another.

long liners:

I have this project file structure

`/vob/project-name/src/`  ==> The ROOT of the project src directory

Under this directory there are subdirs like:
`./utils`, `./common`, `./iplib`, `./ipv6lib`, `./subsystem1`, `./subsystem2` etc

I work on `subsystem1`

The big tags file is HUGE.

I have..

```
setenv  GTAGSROOT /vobs/project-name/src
setenv  GTAGSDBPATH /vobs/project-name/src
```

These take 40mins to build.

I also have a tags file in `./subsystem1/sre`

Currently I have two shell files:

toptags :

```
setenv  GTAGSROOT /vobs/project-name/src
setenv  GTAGSDBPATH /vobs/project-name/src
```

bottomtags:

```
setenv  GTAGSROOT /vobs/project-name/src/subsystem1/src
setenv  GTAGSDBPATH /vobs/project-name/src/subsystem1/src
```

In this way, I can build the TOP project file rarely and the bottomtags every now and then as there is where the churn is.

Also, currently, when I do a `(setq ggtags-update-on-save nil)` then each time I write a file three processes are spawned off that do not die. I got a stern e-mail for sysadmin for keeping 150 processes standing.

Answer (score 1):

`locate-dominating-file` is just what you need.

```
(locate-dominating-file default-directory GTAGS-FILE-NAME)
```

will give you the name of the closest enclosing directory containing a file called `GTAGS-FILE-NAME`, or `nil` if there is no such directory.